# extracting http response code from log

Tags: regex, perl

Apache log file entry

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:20:11:33 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/attach/TWiki/TWikiSite HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
```

Using regex I want to extract the HTTP response code

```
=~ /HTTP/1.1"\s(response_code)\s/
print $response_code
```

I can do such thing in Python or Ruby but don't know if and how can I do it in Perl.

Just extracting a particular value without using multiple split operations.

I just want to scan a line in a file, and print `http_response_code` placed at `/HTTP/1.1"\s(response_code)\s/`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this in perl, this is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, "test.txt" or die $!;
while( my $string = <FILE> )
{
    if( $string =~ /HTTP\/1.1"\s(\d+)/ )
    {
    print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ perl testRegex.pl 
401
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = qq!64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:20:11:33 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/attach/TWiki/TWikiSite HTTP/1.1" 401 12846!;

if( $line =~ m!HTTP/1.1" +(\d+)! ) {
    print $1, "\n";  # <--- prints: 401
}
```

Comment: Why `qq!...!` when `'...'` will do fine?

Comment: TIMTOWTDI, q!...!, you know, infatuation

Comment: @MiguelPrz: awesome. thanks. one more thing. what if i want to do check for 2 conditions?   if($_ =~ /HTTP\/1.1\"\s(.*?)\s/ and $_ = /:(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/). now if i do print $1 it gives me hour value and the http response code is not accessible. is there a way to store it before checking the second match ?

Comment: What conditions? perhaps make another question

Comment: @MiguelPrz: sorry for not being clear. I want to extract 2 values from the line. Http response code and hr value from the same log file line. SO i do if($_ =~ /HTTP\/1.1\"\s(.*?)\s/ **and** $_ = /:(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/). now $1 becomes what i evaluate in the second condition after AND , so the $1 when printed becomes the hr value extracted and the http response code extracted before AND is inaccessible.

Comment: @user1590733 why using two conditions, when one condition can do the job?

Comment: if( $_ =~ /:(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).*HTTP\/1.1"\s(\d+)/ ) will do the job alone, you can access these backreferences as $1, $2, ...

Comment: or if you really want to do it with two conditions then, one way is to do it like this: if( ($_ =~ /HTTP\/1.1"\s(\d+)/) && (print $1, "\n") && ($_ =~ /:(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/ ) )

Answer (score 0):

A regex is unnecessary here. `split` is faster and more convenient.

```
my $line = '64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:20:11:33 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/attach/TWiki/TWikiSite HTTP/1.1" 401 12846';

my $response_code = (split ' ', $line)[-2];
print $response_code;
```

**output**

```
401
```

Comment: thanks but i think in a long file when there is no consistency of spaces , using the other method is more reliable. appreciate your help.

Comment: split always takes a regex as it's first argument, even if it's delimited by quotes

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: No. From [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html): `As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a *literal string* composed of a single space character such as ' '`. It is also the default if no pattern is supplied.

Comment: @Borodin: No. The keyword would be *emulates*, which it does so using a regex. Split ALWAYS uses regexes. Read the rest of the paragraph: "..and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were /\s+/".

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: I don't know what you're saying. There is no other way to get the behaviour you get with a literal space. It behaves differently from `/\s+/`.

Comment: @Borodin: I am not sure what is confusing. I am quoting the same paragraph of documentation you did: `Any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were /\s+/`. By the way, the split version is 6 times slower.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: I have explained that I am confused because `split ' '` is *different* from `split /\s+/` and you seem to be saying they are the same. It is now clear that you are simply spoiling for a fight and I am not interested.

Comment: @Borodin: They are different only because `split ' '` removes leading whitespace first. On a string without leading whitespace, `split ' '` and `split /\s+/` are equivalent, and the former still splits the string using a regex.